# Parameter Expansion Regex?

Tags: regex, linux, variables, parameter-expansion

I have a question regarding parameter expansion in Groovy.  I have a variable called : `${My_Version}` now I have seen that you can only use the first 4 digits of the variable with the following possibilities : `${My_Version[0..4]}`.

Now I have the following problem I would like to use a Regex parameter to filter out software versions like 10.0.0. The corresponding Regex parameter is : ^(\d+.)?(\d+.)?(*|\d+)[;]

How can I use this Regex parameter from this variable. Thank you for your help.

I've been thinking about something like : `${My_Version[^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)[;]]}`

Comment: Do you mean like `^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$` ?

Comment: Yes I need some special details from the variable. How I can use regex with parameter expansion ?